# Regex to include latin characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a Regex to ensure a Password has upper and lowercase characters and limited to a few symbols:

```
^(?:(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&,;.:-_])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&,;.:-_]+)?$
```

NOTE: it allow empty password. I am checking that another way.

However it does not allow the use of latin characters such as ç, á, õ, etc.

How can I add this type of characters?

**UPDATE**

I am trying to create a Regex for Password validation that is in sync with Microsoft options, e.g:

```
RequireDigit (Default = true) 
  Requires a number between 0-9 in the password.

RequireNonAlphanumeric (Default = true)     
  Requires a non-alphanumeric character in the password.

RequireUppercase (Default = true)   
  Requires an upper case character in the password.

RequireLowercase (Default = true)   
  Requires a lower case character in the password.

RequiredUniqueChars (Default = 1)   
  Requires the number of distinct characters in the password
```

Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x

So I would like to have a Regex with block for each one so I can change it simply by adding or removing the rule and do any combination.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Don't limit symbols. Also, use character classes `\p{Ll}` is any lowercase letter in any script. [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) covers this

Comment: The more rules you set for a password, the more targeted an attack becomes.  Do not filter any characters, its all salted and hashed anyway _right_?

Comment: Please don't make us follow your weird rules. A minimum character length should be enough.

Comment: It allows for an empty password because you encased the entire thing in a capture group (why?) and followed it with a `?`, making the entire pattern optional. Even ignoring that, the inner pattern allows for strings between 3 and unlimited characters in length. 3 is pretty low, and I'm sure you will want an upper limit too, right?

Comment: If, for some weird reason, you **must** validate passwords, at least allow any character from any script to work and don't limit the characters to a specific set: `^(?=\P{Ll}*\p{Ll})(?=\P{Lu}*\p{Lu})(?=\P{N}*\p{N})(?=.*[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{C}]).{8,}$`

Comment: Are you aware of Dictionary attacks? Its one of the first steps someone will take to try and breach an account. Basically run through items in a dictionary until you get one that matches, or exhaust your dictionary. Now that we have that covered, lets think about what you are doing. If an attacker has a dictionary with all sorts of varying types of passwords, it will take them much longer to exhaust through them. `// continued`

Comment: However now you have limited the passwords that can be entered (which suggests that you are storing in plain text which is an **absolute no-no**).  You are giving an attacker a clear rule-set to filter their dictionaries on.  Must contain both upper and lower?  Ok now the attacker has eliminated x number of dictionary items.  Cannot contain latin characters?  Ok now they have reduced their dictionary even more so. What you are doing might seem like you are increasing the security, is ultimately _decreasing_ it.

Comment: @maccetture I am hashing the passwords. I just updated my question to better explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: @ctwheels I just added an update explaining what I am trying to do ... Maybe I was not clear on my initial text.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you want such as ç, á, and õ to fulfull the lowercase character requirement (and likewise for their uppercase counterparts)? That wouldn't be in line with C#'s RequireLowercase and RequireUppercase, which check for `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]`.

Comment: @CAustin I think you are right. I just checked the code in Github: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Core/PasswordValidator.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Overview

It's generally bad practice to restrict passwords, so if that's the intention, please don't use the following regex. In any case, I understand some people like to at least ensure some character sets exist (uppercase, lowercase, number, symbol, etc.) and that there are special cases when things like this are needed. The regex below ensures at least one lowercase, uppercase, number and symbol (in any language/script) exists in a string of at least 8 characters.

As comments below the question suggest, restricting passwords to a specific set of characters or a specific format is just asking for trouble. As suggested by [@maccettura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2457029/maccettura), an attacker can filter a Dictionary attack and eliminate a great number of dictionary items that don't match your password format. Writing, for example `[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&,;.:-_]`, the attacker can simply remove any passwords containing characters other than the ones in the list. That list also only contains 75 characters. How many permutations of 75 characters exist? For passwords that are 8 characters in length that's `680,240,886,192,000` permutations (less if we remove the ones that don't match the regex below). How long will it take your CPU to crack the password?

See the following StackExchange posts on passwords:

- [Password Cracking in 2010 and Beyond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833669/password-cracking-in-2010-and-beyond)
- [Password validation in login form](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21674/password-validation-in-login-form)

Other articles:

- [Password Rules Are Bullshit](https://blog.codinghorror.com/password-rules-are-bullshit/) (by Jeff Atwood)

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/PLwJEP/1)

```
^(?=\P{Ll}*\p{Ll})(?=\P{Lu}*\p{Lu})(?=\P{N}*\p{N})(?=.*[^\p{‌​L}\p{N}\p{C}]).{8,}$
```

### Explanation

`\p{x}` represents a Unicode general category or named block specified by `x`

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?=\P{Ll}*\p{Ll})` Ensures at least one lowercase letter in any script exists
- `(?=\P{Lu}*\p{Lu})` Ensures at least one uppercase letter in any script exists
- `(?=\P{N}*\p{N})` Ensures at least one number character in any script exists
- `(?=.*[^\p{‌​L}\p{N}\p{C}])` Ensures any character other than a letter, number or control character exists
- `.{8,}` Ensures the password is at least `8` characters in length (and isn't limited on the upper bound)
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: May I ask what is the advantage of using the negation in your lookaheads? e.g. is there any advantage of using `(?=\P{Ll}*\p{Ll})` vs using `(?=.*\p{Ll})`

Comment: @JackPRead it makes it very slightly faster. Look at the number of steps on my original regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/PLwJEP/1) and when I replaced a single negated set [here](https://regex101.com/r/PLwJEP/2). Steps go up by 1. Alternatively, `.*?` may also be used (no additional steps), but in the case where no matches are found `.*?` will take more steps (as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/PLwJEP/4)) to complete than `\P{Ll}` as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/PLwJEP/3) because it backtracks.

Comment: After thinking about it that makes complete sense. Thanks. Actually if you make the quantifier on the wild card lazy you can get the same result. Example [here](https://regex101.com/r/w60GgG/1). I think it may still be better your way if searching a large string though.

Comment: @JackPRead I updated my previous comment to include the lazy quantifier. Whilst it does suggest it may be equivalent it's actually slower when the pattern fails to match the string (27 steps as opposed to 4 in this case). This is due to backtracking.

Comment: Some trivia.. This may/may not be desirable, I don't know. Of the some 9763 characters this matches `[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{C}]`, includes these as well `\p{Block=Combining_Diacritical_Marks}` U+300 - U+36f

Comment: @sln personally, I’d allow them cause why restrict it? But you could always just add `\p{M}` to the negated set