# Regex for complex Password with upper case, lower case, digit and special characters (Python)

Tags: regex

First time I post something here, so I apologize if I'll do something wrong.
I tried already looking for the answer in existing topics, but I was not able to find something that was working 100% for my case.

I basically need to build a python RegEx that will match a password with the following requirements:

- At least 1 upper case character
- At least 1 lower case character
- At least 1 digit character
- At least 1 special character between the following !"£$%^&?
- Spaces cannot be included in the password

The minimum length should be 10 characters, the maximum should be 20.

In the following examples:

- Password!123
- Password!123 test test test

I would expect to match "Password!123" in both examples, however in the second example the match should stop ad the "3", the "test" (or part of it) should not be included in the match.

So far I built the following:

```
\b(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!"£$%^&]).{10,20}
```

But, according to regexr.com , If I test the following:
Password!123 test  test test

Then I get this match

**Password!123 test  t**est test

While I would like to have the following

**Password!123** test  test test

Any idea on how I could solve this?

Thanks in advance to anyone that will help!!!

KR

Adriano

Comment: Instead of `.{10,20}` use `\S{10,20}`. Note that the starting `\b` will cause `!Password123` to fail.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48214008/regex-to-include-latin-characters/48214335#48214335) recent post I answered about password validation using regex.

Comment: Also, what language are you using? Each language implements regex differently

Comment: Use [`^(?=\P{Ll}*\p{Ll})(?=\P{Lu}*\p{Lu})(?=\P{N}*\p{N})(?=.*[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{C}])\S{8,}$`](https://regex101.com/r/PLwJEP/5)

Comment: Thanks guys, this one seems to work perfectly:

(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!?])\S{10,20}

the language is python, it was stated in the title and in the request :)

Comment: No that last one doesn't work, it matches "LongPassword 123 ! test", because the four parentheses can find a letter, number or symbol anywhere, even if they have to look beyond spaces to do that. To do what you mean, replace all dots by \S

Comment: I see, you're right, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation)

Answer (score 1):

This regex seems to work:

```
(?=\S{10,})(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[0-9])(?=\S*[!£$%^&\"])(?<!\S)\S{10,20}(?=\s|\Z)
```

A test can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/lIp2m2/1)

Comment: Note that the `(?=\S{10,})` part was just added to lower the number of steps.